# Initializing an enum of generic type from rawValue

Tags: swift, generics

I'm experimenting with custom operators in Swift *(EXPERIMENTING. I do not need a lecture about why custom operators are bad)* and I thought, hmm, EnumType(rawValue:) is a bit long. Maybe I could fix this with an operator? So I wrote:

```
infix operator ∑
func ∑ <T,U:RawRepresentable>(lhs:T,rhs:U.Type) {
    rhs(rawValue: lhs)
}
```

Which as intended would be used like this example:

```
enum DiceResult: Int {
    case one = 1, two, three, four, five, six
}
let roll = 1 ∑ DiceResult //DiceResult.one
```

But the code I wrote gives me this error:

> Non-nominal type 'U' does not support explicit initialization

Honestly I didn't expect what I wrote to work anyway, and I'm not even certain something like what I'm trying to write is at all possible in Swift. Can anybody shed some light whether I can do something like this, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is that you treat the operand types `U`, `T` as independent. But the type of the left operand must be the `RawValue` type of the right operand. So this would compile:

```
infix operator ∑
func ∑ <U: RawRepresentable>(lhs: U.RawValue, rhs: U.Type) -> U? {
    return rhs.init(rawValue: lhs)
}
```

You can then use it as

```
enum DiceResult: Int {
    case one = 1, two, three, four, five, six
}
let roll = 1 ∑ DiceResult.self
```

`.self` is required to access the type as a value.
Unfortunately this is not much shorter than

```
let roll = DiceResult(rawValue: 1)
```

Comment: It's seems it's still useful, since I can assign the type to a constant e.g. 1 ∑ DICE
And, uh, don't worry this isn't going into any public codebase. 